# For bounded functions, Convergence in measure implies convergence in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space. $f_n,f:X \to\mathbb{R}$ such that there is $M\in\mathbb{R}$ where $|f_n(x)|,|f(x)|\le M$

prove that if $f_n\to f$ in measure than $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mu)$

My attempt:

Let $A=\{x\in X|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon \}$ than $\lim\mu(A)=0$ and also:
$\int_X|f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu \le \int_A|f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu \le \int_A|f_n(x)|+|f(x)|d\mu \le\int_A2Md\mu=2M\mu (A)$ now if we take the limit we get the result.

Is this correct? seems too simple too me, but I hope I'm right.

Comment: Where does the first inequality come from?

Comment: if $A\subset X$ than the integral over A is less or equal to the integral over X, no? Maybe I need to prove that A is measurable

Comment: Your first inequality bounds above an integral over $X$ by an integral over $A$ though. This is the wrong way around since $A \subseteq X$.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed... thank you. would any of you know how to solve this then?

Comment: $A$ is clearly measurable. (Though you really should be indexing these sets by $n$.) The claim you make in your comment is correct, but that is not the inequality you write in your question.

Comment: The first inequality should be $\int_A |f_n(x) - f(x)| d\mu(x) + \epsilon \mu(A^c)$. Your other inequalities show that the first quantity does go to 0 and it is easy to see that the second quantity goes to $\epsilon$ by convergence in measure. Finally, $\epsilon$ is arbitrary so everything goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can write
$$\int_X |f_n - f| d \mu = \int_{A_n} |f_n - f| d \mu + \int_{X \setminus A_n}|f_n - f| d \mu$$
for $A_n = \{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \varepsilon\}$ so that $\mu(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Then, for $x \in X \setminus A_n$, you have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ and so you can bound
\begin{align*}
\int_X |f_n - f| d \mu &\leq \int_{A_n} 2M d \mu + \int_{X \setminus A_n} \varepsilon d \mu
\\& = 2M \mu(A_n) + \mu(X \setminus A_n) \varepsilon
\\& \leq 2M \mu(A_n) + \mu(X) \varepsilon
\end{align*}
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, sending $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives 
$$\int_X |f_n - f| d \mu \leq 2M \mu(A_n) \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! is there a simple explanation as to why $\int_{A\cup B} = \int_A + \int_B$? it sounds logical but I don't think we ever proved it before in class.

Comment: Oh nevermind, we showed that it's a measure. Thank you!

Comment: The simple explanation is "it's true for simple functions and you can extend this by the MCT" (i.e. check it for simple functions and then use the MCT and an approximation argument to get it for non-negative things. Finally decompose a general integrable function into positive and negative parts)